# Using a machine certificate for SSL client authentication

Tags: windows, ssl, client-certificate

Assuming a web site enforces SSL client authentication and the client machine (running Windows) is equipped with a certificate which the server accepts for that purpose. The certificate resides in the **machine** certificate store.

Under what conditions can a user fire up a browser (IE or anything else which relies on the Windows cert store, and runs as a user process) and authenticate to the web site with the machine certificate? Can any user access the certificate, or do they need to be admins, or maybe hold a particular permission (and which)?

Comment: Are you asking with regards to trust, in that the browser will trust the certificate in the store, or in some other context?

Comment: @Ramhound I am asking with regards to user permissions. Who has permission to authenticate with a certificate in the machine store (not the user store)? All users? Just admins? Users with a particular permission?